# UserForm w/ ComboBox - enter value to database based on selected option

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I have a UserForm for entering survey data, with 32 ComboBoxes. Each ComboBox has the same set of responses and each response has a corresponding score. When the user hits Save, rather than the response getting saved to the database I would like the score. Here are the scores:

Muy en desacuerdo: -2
En desacuerdo: -1
Ni de acuerdo/en desacuerdo: 0
De acuerdo: 1
Muy de acuerdo: 2

However, in some cases the responses are to be reverse-scored (so "muy de acuerdo" would receive a -2 rather than a 2).

Someone earlier gave me a code that loops through and assigns the correct option list to each ComboBox:
    comboItems() = Array("Muy en desacuerdo", _
                     "En desacuerdo", _
                     "Ni de acuerdo/en desacuerdo", _
                     "De acuerdo", _
                     "Muy de acuerdo")

```
For Each ct In Me.Controls

If TypeName(ct) = "ComboBox" And _
    ct.Name <> "cboGender" And _
    ct.Name <> "cboDepartment" Then

    For i = LBound(comboItems) To UBound(comboItems)
        ct.AddItem comboItems(i)
    Next i

End If

Next ct
```

Then here is the sample of the code that adds each field to the database:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'Copy input values to sheet.
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("CRUDO")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
ws.Unprotect ""
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFecha.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtTime.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtPlace.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cboDepartment.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtMunicipality.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.txtGroupName.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.txtComponent.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.txtComments.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.txtName.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.txtBirthDate.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.cboGender.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.cboAE1A.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.cboAE2A.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 14).Value = Me.cboAE3A.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 15).Value = Me.cboAE4A.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 16).Value = Me.cboAE5A.Value
```

So, in the example above, let's say cboAE1A is scored normally according to the scale above. AE2A and AE5A, however, are reverse scored.

Is this possible? What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to save the score and not the actual response, then you should change the code to:

```
.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFecha.ListIndex -2
```

And if you want to reverse the score on AE2A:

```
.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = -(Me.txtTime.ListIndex -2)
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But for each question there are 5 response options, each with a different score. Wouldn't that code enter a -2 regardless of the response that is chosen? I need the code to insert a -2 if "muy en desacuerdo" is selected, -1 if "en desacuerdo", 0 if "ni de acuerdo ni en desacuerdo", etc.

Comment: It will not always produce "-2" result. The score will be according to the ListIndex value which starts at 0, so you have to modify it by subtracting 2. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense and is a clever solution! I am new to VBA and expected it to be much harder to implement. Thanks much for your help!